# Conditionally display tag using MVS Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This code:

```
<td class="text-left">
    @Html.RestrictedActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Parameter", new[] { "Admin" }, this.User, new { vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate, createNew = false })
    @Html.RestrictedActionLink("Copy", "Edit", "Parameter", new[] { "Admin" }, this.User, new { vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate })
    @Html.RestrictedActionLink("Cancel...", "", "", new[] { "Admin" }, User, null, new { @class = "CancelParam", vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate})                   
</td>
```

...renders 3 achor tags:

```
<td class="text-left">
    <a href="/Parameter/Edit?vendorId=CT1%20%20&amp;effectiveDate=07%2F01%2F2016%2000%3A00%3A00&amp;createNew=False">Edit</a>
    <a href="/Parameter/Edit?vendorId=CT1%20%20&amp;effectiveDate=07%2F01%2F2016%2000%3A00%3A00">Copy</a>
    <a class="CancelParam" effectiveDate="07/01/2016 00:00:00" href="javascript:void(0)" vendorId="CT1  ">Cancel...</a>                
</td>
```

But this code, which I added to only display the Cancel and Copy links if the associated model bool propertyu is set,

```
<td class="text-left">
    @Html.RestrictedActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Parameter", new[] { "Admin" }, this.User, new { vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate, createNew = false })
    @{
        if (Model.AllowCancel)
        {
            Html.RestrictedActionLink("Copy", "Edit", "Parameter", new[] { "Admin" }, this.User, new { vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate });
        }

        if (@Model.AllowCancel)
        {
            Html.RestrictedActionLink("Cancel...", "", "", new[] { "Admin" }, User, null, new { @class = "CancelParam", vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate, disabled = !Model.AllowCancel });
        }
    }
```

Did not produce any Copy or Cancel links in the HTML even though when I traced, I witnessed that the RestrictedActionLink methods were called.

I am a Razor noob, and a lot of other words could go in front of Noob.

Comment: @if (Model.AllowCancel)
        {
            @Html.RestrictedActionLink("Copy", "Edit", "Parameter", new[] { "Admin" }, this.User, new { vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate });
        }

Comment: Damn StackO has all sorts of issues when inside the firewall, incuding not being able to post my own answer. I also have issues with editing a post too long (more than 60 seconds or so). If I do, it won't post or I go into human verification mode. Please post the 1st comment as the solution to claim you points.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is slightly wrong here. Try this:

```
@Html.RestrictedActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Parameter", new[] { "Admin" }, this.User, new { vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate, createNew = false })

@if (Model.AllowCancel)
{
    @Html.RestrictedActionLink("Copy", "Edit", "Parameter", new[] { "Admin" }, this.User, new { vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate });
}

@if (Model.AllowCancel)
{
    @Html.RestrictedActionLink("Cancel...", "", "", new[] { "Admin" }, User, null, new { @class = "CancelParam", vendorId = Model.VendorId, effectiveDate = Model.EffectiveDate, disabled = !Model.AllowCancel });
}
```